# Why does Magento remove my styles in content, and how do I avoid this?

Tags: magento

I'm trying to insert a form into the content of one of my pages and every time I copy the form code including the `<style type="text/css">` into the content and save it, Magento removes the style tags and a lot more, thus making my form not look the way I programmed it to; this becomes very annoying when I'm trying to implement my own custom css. How can I stop Magento from doing this?

My code is pretty straightforward:

```
<html>
<head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../includes/form_style.css">
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
        </head>
    <body>
        <div id="form11">
            <h1>Form</h1>
            <form method="post" action="#">
                <table id="table11">
                    <tr><td><p>Name:</p></td><td><input type="text" name="name"/></td></tr>
                    <tr><td><p>Email:</p></td><td><input type="text" name="email"/></td></tr>
                    <tr><td><p>Phone:</p></td><td><input type="text" name="phone"/></td></tr>
                    <tr><td><p>House:</p></td><td><input type="text" name="house"/></td></tr>
                    <tr><td><p>Street:</p></td><td><input type="text" name="street"/></td></tr>
                    <tr><td><p>PostCode:</p></td><td><input type="text" name="postcode"/></td></tr>
                    <tr><td><p>Width (m):</p></td><td><input type="range" name="points" id="points" value="0" min="0" max="100" data-highlight="true"></td></tr>
                    <tr><td><p>Length (m):</p></td><td><input type="range" name="points" id="points" value="0" min="0" max="100" data-highlight="true"></td></tr>
                    <tr><td><p>Carpet Type:</p></td><td><select name="carpettype">
                                                    <option value="carpet1">Carpet1</option>
                                                    <option value="carpet2">Carpet2</option>
                                                    <option value="carpet3">Carpet3</option>
                                                    <option value="carpet4">Carpet4</option>
                                                    <option value="carpet5">Carpet5</option>


                                                </select></td></tr>
                    <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></td></tr>


                </table>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="image">
        <img src="../Desktop/freesamplesrightpanel.png" alt="freesamplesrightpanel" width="470" height="835" />
        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Are you putting all this code in side a CMS page ?

Comment: yes in the content section of the cms page

Comment: Since it is a CMS page, Magento will keep removing the html, body tags every time, your best way way to add your styling is to edit the css file of the theme located in the skin folder, or add a style tag at the end of the content of the page.